# How to create groups of a multidimensional array with the same value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array, where I want to group values together based on a value they have in common. Basically I'm creating a program where you can order parts from different suppliers and when you submit the order an array get created with all the values.

After that I need to create groups of parts with the same supplier so I can create one email for each supplier. I have replicated this problem on a smaller scale and trying to create tables for each supplier first.

This is the array I'm using

```
$result = Array(
    0 => Array (
        'supplier' => 'Supplier 1',
        'descr' => 'Product 1',
        'id' => '123',
        'quantity' => '5',
    ),
    1 => Array (
        'supplier' => 'Supplier 1',
        'descr' => 'Product 2',
        'id' => '345',
        'quantity' => '1',
    ),
    2 => Array (
        'supplier' => 'Supplier 2',
        'descr' => 'Product 3',
        'id' => '567',
        'quantity' => '10',
    ),
    3 => Array (
        'supplier' => 'Supplier 1',
        'descr' => 'Product 4',
        'id' => '789',
        'quantity' => '1',
    ),
    4 => Array (
        'supplier' => 'Supplier 3',
        'descr' => 'Product 5',
        'id' => '111',
        'quantity' => '6',
    ),
    5 => Array (
        'supplier' => 'Supplier 4',
        'descr' => 'Product 6',
        'id' => '222',
        'quantity' => '30',
    )
);
```

I thought maybe if I would group them first based on supplier I would have more succes. I did that as follows

```
$arr = array();
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    $arr[$value['supplier']][$key] = $value;
}

ksort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

Than I started creating the tables like this

```
echo '<table>';

foreach($arr as $id) {
    foreach($id as $key => $value) {

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$value['supplier'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$value['descr'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$value['id'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$value['quantity'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

        // different supplier so start new table
        if(current($value['supplier']) != next($value['supplier'])){
            echo '</table><table>';
        }
    }
}

echo '</table>';
```

But this creates just one table. And when I change the operator to `==` it creates 5 separate tables.

/edit

Perfect outcome would be

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Supplier 2</td>
            <td>Product 3</td>
            <td>567</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table> <!-- One table with 3 different parts but same supplier -->
        <tr>
            <td>Supplier 1</td>
            <td>Product 1<td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Supplier 1</td>
            <td>Product 2</td>
            <td>345</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Supplier 1</td>
            <td>Product 4</td>
            <td>789</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Supplier 3</td>
            <td>Product 5</td>
            <td>111</td>
            <td>30</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Supplier 4/td>
            <td>Prodcut 6</td>
            <td>222</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Okay , so what is the question ? Also current value and next value of `$value['supplier']` is always eual

Comment: @ok_arjun Like I said 'create groups of parts with the same supplier' I need to know when the supplier of the next loop does not equal the current so I can and the current table and create a new one for the next supplier.

Comment: So u want to keep single table for same supplier , so if there are 4 different types of supplier , there d be 4  tables , am I ryt ?

Comment: @ok_arjun Yes, I've added the perfect outcome so it's more clear what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your loop accordingly

```
foreach($arr as $id) {
foreach($id as $key => $value) {

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$value['supplier'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value['descr'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value['id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value['quantity'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

}
// different supplier so start new table
echo '</table><table>';
```

}

Comment: This would just make one table ...?

Comment: no it gives u four different tables , as there are four different suppliers

Comment: @ok_arjun Worked exactly like I needed it too! Thanks